# How I can get updated, created or failed data after insert into table?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a lot of objects that need to be inserted into the table. After insertion, there may be three options: created, updated and failed. It looks like `upsert` but I need a detailed result.
I tried to use `on_conflict_do_update` but then I won’t find out which ones were updated, created and failed.
I really do not want to use iteration and handle each item in exception block, maybe you will have some options?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the information? One way to do this is by using Postgres triggers that execute specific actions when a row is inserted or update. Define a trigger that executes a function before insert or update on your table. Handle what you want to do with the created/updated data in the trigger function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION handle_modify() RETURNS trigger AS $modify$
   BEGIN
      IF TG_OP='INSERT' THEN
         --do something with created data NEW.data
      END IF;
      IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN
         --do something with updated data NEW.data or OLD.data
      END IF;

   END
$modify$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER modify AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON your_table
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE modify();
```